# What is the escape character for '=' symbol in GNU make?

Tags: build, makefile, gnu

I want to call a makefile by passing the environment variable `CPU_TYPE` and its value  `-mcpu=603` as command line argument to that makefile. I am entering the below command

`make -f make_file CPU_TYPE=-mcpu=603`

But its given error because environment variable value is having `=` symbol. How to escape this equal symbol in the environment value.

Note : I cant add this environment variable or any other variable inside `make_file`. I have to pass it as command line arugments only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Improbable possibility

There shouldn't be any problem, but maybe you are running afoul of a seldom-used shell feature.

If you use `set -k` in a running shell, or use `sh -k` to run a shell, it will treat anything that looks like an environment variable as an environment variable.

You probably already know that shells other than the C shell family can set an environment variable for a single command by adding it before the command:

```
PATH="/somewhere/else:$PATH" cmdname -opts file1 file2
```

The command itself sees the modified environment; the shell's search for `cmdname` is not altered.  However, with `set -k` in effect, anything that looks like an environment variable is treated as one:

```
cmdname -opts PATH="/somewhere/else:$PATH" file1 file2
```

You can validate this by using `env`, for example, as the command.  There are sound reasons (such as the `dd` command) for not making this the default behaviour.

#### Against the hypothesis

Against this hypothesis, I don't know of a shell that objects to the '`=`' in the environment value.  It would be a nuisance if there was such a restriction.

#### Plain GNU Make is OK

However, I'm able to do:

```
make CFLAGS='-Dxyz=pqr' progname
```

and, with `set -k` in effect, I can also do:

```
make -e CFLAGS='-Dxyz=pqr' progname
```

In both cases, the compilation takes the value specified via the command line as overriding what is set in the makefile.

The single quotes aren't seen by `make`; they are removed by the shell, of course.  You can perfectly well omit them and I get the same result.  I'm running using `bash` on MacOS X, but I'd expect the same results on any Unix-like system using any of the standard POSIX-ish shells (Bourne, Korn, Bash).

Comment: You can hide the equals sign from sh -k by quoting it: `make 'CFLAGS=-Dxyz=pqr'` or `make CFLAGS\=-Dxyz\=pqr` have the desired effect of having the argument interpreted normally by _make_ rather than by the shell.  (At least with bash 3.2.48 on Mac OS X.)

Answer (score 0):

try \= instead of =. [this tutorial shows you some examples but dosnt contain how to escape the equal symbol](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/ask-mr-make/8442-gnu-make-escaping-a-walk-on-the-wild-side).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure there is a direct way to achieve what you want.

But perhaps you might modify your *Makefile* so that it sets the `CPU_TYPE` by e.g. reading a file. You might put in your `make_file` something like

```
CPU_TYPE=$(shell cat $(CPU_TYPE_FILE))
```

and then create a file `my603.cputype` with e.g.

```
echo '-mcpu=603' > my603.cputype
```

and finally run make as

```
make -f make_file CPU_TYPE_FILE=my603.cputype
```